# Detect if Save event is triggered manually or by autosave

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a small piece of code to export the VBProject components before saving the workbook.

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Wb.HasVBProject Then
        If Wb.VBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_none Then
            If vbYes = MsgBox("Do you want to export the VBProject components?", vbYesNo) Then
                ExportWB Wb ' call a function to export the data
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is working fine, but if the Autosave is on the user (me) is asked every few second if it wants to export the project.

I can check if Autosave is On or Off with `Wb.AutoSave`, but is there a way to check if the event was triggered manually or by Autosave, in order to run the code only when someone require a save, not for the Autosave events?

Vincent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400645/distinguish-save-and-autosave-events-in-microsoft-excel-add-in

Comment: @SiddharthRout That link doesn't seem directly relevant. The only answer begins "There is no Autosave in Excel 2003/2007." I don't know the version history, but it seems like the question here involves something which didn't exist 10 years ago.

Comment: The Microsoft article [How AutoSave Impacts add-ins and macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/how-autosave-impacts-addins-and-macros) doesn't sound very encouraging. It outlines a number of potential problems and discusses various work-arounds. In none of its cases did it suggest checking if the save event was auto-triggered, even though for some of its scenarios that could have helped.

Comment: @JohnColeman The point that I was trying to make is that the AutoRecovery save is not a true workbook save. You cannot trap it from `WorkbookBeforeSave`. You will have to do as suggested in that link. Turn auto save off for the workbook and then roll your own autosave.

Comment: @SiddharthRout But is seems that OP isn't talking about AutoRecovery at all but instead is talking about an AutoSave which *is* being trapped by `WorkbookBeforeSave`, the problem being that it is being trapped when OP wishes it weren't.

Comment: @JohnColeman Perhaps wrong choice of words from me? `AutoSave` does trigger the `WorkbookBeforeSave` but you cannot identify whether the `WorkbookBeforeSave` was by `AutoSave` or `Manual`. You will have to disable the Excel's `AutoSave` and write your own `AutoSave` method (if `AutoSave` is really required)

Comment: Sorry for not coming back earlier. The situation is as @JohnColeman mentionned, the AutoSave if for files saved in the cload that trigger the beforeSave event. Thanks for the link on the Microsoft article, in my case I have the "Issue 2" mentioned (apparition of a modal dialog box).

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `ThisWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False`, the effect should be gone. You can place this line e.g. into ThisWorkbook's event `Private Sub Workbook_Open`.
2. You can get the info about if AutoSave is currently enabled for this file, from `ThisWorkbook.AutoSaveOn` (returns True for enabled, or False for disabled).